# Three.js - repositioning vertices in a 'particle' mesh

Tags: three.js, particle-system

I have a basic three.js game working and I'd like to add particles. I've been searching online, including multiple questions here, and the closest I've come to getting a 'particle system' working is using a THREE.BufferGeometry, a THREE.BufferAttribute and a THREE.Points mesh. I set it up like this:

```
const particleMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 10, map: particleTexture, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, transparent: true } );
const particlesGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry;
const particlesCount = 300;
const posArray = new Float32Array(particlesCount * 3);

for (let i = 0; i < particlesCount; i++) {
    posArray[i] = Math.random() * 10;
}

const particleBufferAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(posArray, 3);
particlesGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', particleBufferAttribute );

const particlesMesh = new THREE.Points(particlesGeometry, particleMaterial);
particlesMesh.counter = 0;
scene.add(particlesMesh);
```

**This part works** and displays the particles fine, at their initial positions, but of course I'd like to move them.
I have tried all manner of things, in my 'animate' function, but I am not happening upon the right combination. I'd like to move particles, ideally one vertex per frame.
The current thing I'm doing in the animate function - **which does not work!** - is this:

```
particleBufferAttribute.setXYZ( particlesMesh.counter, objects[0].position.x, objects[0].position.y, objects[0].position.z );
particlesGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', particleBufferAttribute );
//posArray[particlesMesh.counter] = objects[0].position;
particlesMesh.counter ++;
if (particlesMesh.counter > particlesCount) {
     particlesMesh.counter = 0;
}
```

If anyone has any pointers about how to move Points mesh vertices, that would be great.

Alternatively, if this is not at all the right approach, please let me know.

I did find Stemkoski's ShaderParticleEngine, but I could not find any information about how to make it work (the docs are very minimal and do not seem to include examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-set the attribute, but you do need to tell the renderer that the attribute has changed.

```js
particleBufferAttribute.setXYZ( particlesMesh.counter, objects[0].position.x, objects[0].position.y, objects[0].position.z );
particleBufferAttribute.needsUpdate = true; // This is the kicker!
```

By setting `needsUpdate` to `true`, the renderer knows to re-upload that attribute to the GPU.

This might not be  concern for you, but just know that moving particles in this way is expensive, because you re-upload the `position` attribute *every single frame*, which includes all the position data for every particle you *aren't* moving.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's good to know. And yes, performance is a concern. Do you have any idea what a faster approach might be? I've tried one other example but that approach included a THREE.Geometry which isn't recognised now-a-days, and replacing it with a THREE.BufferGeometry did not work. Again, any advice about how to do this better is much appreciated!

Comment: @moosefetcher It depends on the effect you want. If you want all the particles to orbit a point, then make that point the center of your `Points` object, and rotate the whole thing. If your animation follows a pattern, then programming that pattern into the vertex shader is best, passing in a "time" value via a uniform. If you're only moving a subset of your particles, you could break just those particles into their own `Points` to minimize attribute change overhead. etc, etc...

Comment: In this instance I'm adding a spaceship's 'trail' so as each vertex resets its position is set to the position of the ship. I'm having another problem now in that the trail only becomes visible when my camera is oriented to certain rotations  I'm not using OrbitControls, I've got it moving on it's Z axis at a speed controlled by the mouse wheel. But the display issue is probably another question.

Comment: @moosefetcher Indeed, that's another question. And I think I understand--you want a rolling set of point positions. Do you really need points for this? Could you use a collection of `Sprite`s instead? Again, a topic beyond the scope of this question, but some food for thought.